Open platform to visualise bathymetry LiDAR
I have point cloud data that I want to visualise on an open platform, which I can extend tools upon to investigate further.
I was wondering if any offer a visualisation like below, where the bathymetry LiDAR is clearly below the terrain

I'd thought maybe Cesium but wasn't sure? Open to suggestions!

Welcome! Do you have an OS preference or price requirement?  If so, please edit your question and tags to include those details.  Thanks, and again, welcome!
